# C++: duplicate symbol using Makefile and object declaration

Tags: c++, struct, makefile, g++

I have a struct defined in 
**a.h**

```
#IFNDEF
#define A_H
struct a_struct
{
int val;
int val_b;
}a;
#endif
```

and both **main.cpp** and **a.cpp** included the header

```
#include "a.h"
```

when I use makefile with the following:

```
a.o: a.cpp a.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -c $<
main.o: main.cpp a.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -c $<
main: main.o a.o
    g++ -std=c++ $^ -o $@
```

A compilation error occurs:

```
duplicate symbol '_a' in:
    a.o
    main.o
```

Is `a` being redefined in **a.cpp** and **main.cpp**?
Is there a way to resolve this issue without changing **a.h**? 
In case that's not possible, how may I change the code?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `Is a being redefined in a.cpp and main.cpp?` Yes. `Is there a way to resolve this issue without changing a.h?` No

Comment: Why do you not want to change `a.h`? Could you make a copy of it, call it `b.h`, and fix that?

Comment: @Beta @tkausl I wanted to minimize changes to `a.h` as little as possible because it is not owned by me. How can I resolve this issue if I am able to get a hold of `a.h`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `a.h` both declares a data type `struct a_struct` *and* declares `a` as a variable of that type.  Each translation unit that includes that header -- for example, the one based on `a.cpp` and the one based on `main.cpp` will therefore declare its own `a`, and if two such translation units contribute to the same program then undefined behavior results.  The program being rejected on account of duplicate symbols is one possible (and fairly common) manifestation of the UB arising from such circumstances.

So,

> Is a being redefined in a.cpp and main.cpp?

Yes.  The declaration of `a` included into the translation unit of each of those source files directly causes `a` to be defined in each.  Technically, these declarations are not themselves the definitions, but that's a bit hair-splitting.

> Is there a way to resolve this issue without changing a.h?

If the program were modified so that only one translation unit in it `#include`s `a.h`, whether directly or indirectly, then it would not have multiple definitions of `a` (from the source it now has them).  It is unclear whether that would be a viable solution for you, but that seems doubtful.

> In case that's not possible, how may I change the code?

The simplest change would be to remove the declaration of `a` from `a.h`:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
struct a_struct
{
int val;
int val_b;
};  // <-- the main change is here
#endif
```

If you actually need an external variable `a` of type `struct a_struct` then you should declare it `extern` in the header by adding

```
extern struct a_struct a;
```

to the header

AND

adding a non-(explicitly-)`extern` declaration of `a` in exactly one of the .cpp files:

```
struct a_struct a;
```

From its name, it seems like file `a.cpp` would be the right place for the latter, but if you don't want to modify that then you can use `main.cpp` instead.